# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, syntax-error

I have been stuck at this error for days, can any kind soul decipher this error? The alert shows the correct data that is needed but somehow the push() method just doesn't work.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `sub` defined?

Comment: @techfoobar Hi! I've changed sub to layer because it was a little confusing and added more codes which I hope would help in identifying the error. Thanks guys!

Comment: Why can't you just paste the code you're _actually using_. You've got `layers` and `layer` here, a switch statement with **one case**.. I'm almost positive this isn't the original code. Or maybe your problem is because you've mispelt `layers` as `layer`?

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(result['layerId'], layer)` before the offending line and tell us what the result is in your browser's console? You're getting this error because `layer` does not contain an attribute by whatever name `result['layerId']` returns.

Comment: Your code doesn't work - function is not closed. Chrome reporting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. Can you paste whole function?

Comment: @Aesthete Hi, my apologies, but because only that particular switch case is the only case that is not working so i thought it was only relevant to only paste that case :/

Comment: @Carlos Hi! I've followed your instructions and this was what it returned. "16 [Array[0]]"

Comment: Ok, `layer` is an array that does not contain an attribute named `16`. You'll need to think about what you're trying to accomplish to figure out how to fix that problem. For example, do you expect `layer` to be populated with something? If so, you'll need to investigate why it hasn't been populated. Perhaps as Aesthete suggested, you mean to use `layers` there.

Comment: I was thinking about pasting whole function here, and then I will be able to test it on my end. This code is really hard to debug...

Comment: Cool - how do you call this function? Can you specify some example parameters which are supposed to work?

Comment: can you just paste the entire javascript only using pastebin

Comment: Also there are still some bug in the code - one additional curly bracket before second case, and missing curly bracket in the end to close the function...

Comment: @DanWich Hi! I've made some additional editing to my codes. Sorry that i can't paste everything here because some parts are confidential in my .js are confidential. layer was a mistake on my part when i was copying over my codes but '16 [Array[0]]' is what i got when i used 'console.log(result['layerId'], layers);' Will look into your suggestion and answer, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Carlos Hmm, my function is to display a popup table with some data when a marker is placed on a spot in the map :)

Comment: OK. Now I can paste it to Chrome without parsing/syntax errors. Is it a function you actually use? As you're consistently using `layers` variable, but right after `switch` you have `if` statement with this `alert`. And under this `alert` you have `layer` variable which is `undefined` inside function scope (is it defined as global somewhere?), so you can't use it as an array, and then push anything to it. What will happen if you change it to `layers`?

Comment: @Carlos Hiya! Yup, layers is defined as a global var at 'var layers = new Array();' and it is a function I use, I think the 'layer' you were referring to was the 'layer' that i copied and paste by mistake without checking. It is actually 'layers' and that is how i got the error. :/

Comment: So this is an answer for your question I should add - typo?

Comment: @Carlos ' if(idLayer == "alu") { } ' actually works because i can see my data in the inspect element console. That is why I'm getting so desperate! DX

Comment: @Carlos Erm, i used 'layers[result['layerId']].push(result);' and got the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really easy to tell, but basing on a comments, the object you're calling `push` method on is probably `undefined`. And this `object` should be an `array`.

Replace this line:

```
layer[result['layerId']].push(result);
```

With following code:

```
if("undefined" != typeof layer[result['layerId']]) {
    layer[result['layerId']].push(result);
}
else {
    layer[result['layerId']] = new Array();
    layer[result['layerId']].push(result);
}
```

Let me know if it works.